# compare two date value in qlik sense

Tags: date, qliksense

In qlik sense, there are two fields' (Package_Packing_End_Working_Date, Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date) value i need to compare, if equal, then return 1, if not equal, then return 0, the fields store date value.

So my formula, if(Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date = Package_Packing_End_Working_Date,1,0)

but it all return 0, may i know which part is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your dates can have a time that could lead to this behavior. You can try to use  [daystart](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/daystart.htm) function `if(daystart(Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date) = daystart(Package_Packing_End_Working_Date), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Qlik have several problems when works with dates. Try to force to be a date:
Date(Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date,'dd/mm/yyyy') and then try to do the if sentence. Other solutions is try to convert into number with following sentence:

Num(Date#(Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))

With this sentece you can compare two number with:

```
if(
    Num(Date#(Pkg_Wave_Sum_Working_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))-
    Num(Date#(Pkg_Wave_End_Sum_Working_Date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'))=0,1,0)
```